# How can I deploy a VB.NET application that will work on multiple Oracle clients?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

Working in Visual Studio 2015, I have a VB app that I need to deploy to multiple clients.  The app works ok as long as I'm deploying to a machine with the exact same version of the Oracle.DataAccess.dll as it was developed with.  But the machines I need to deploy to have varying versions of the Oracle Client.  Is there any way to make the application work for different versions of the Oracle Client?

Comment: Your application is going to have a tight dependency on the Oracle Client and ODP.NET and so you will need to bundle ODP.NET with your application to make sure it has what it needs. You can't rely on whatever is on the target machine. See discussion below which boils down to using the ODAC xcopy release for ODP.NET unmanaged, or Nuget for ODP.NET managed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use client-less Oracle connection. Refer to this [article](https://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/accessing-oracle-database-without-installing-oracle-client/). Or how about client-less [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`?

the problem with oracle is that a specific client wouldn't work with `Oracle.Dataaccess.dll` that has different version. Sometimes version might be just a bit different, like client 1.2.0.206 and it wouldn't work with 1.2.0.212.

You can also try not to distribute the dll because, I believe that Oracle client installs odp.net folder where there is DLL that matches that client and it is registered in GAC. But the problem can be that dll you used for dev is of higher version. You can try to tweak `app.config` to set version range for this dll. [Read about redirecting assembly version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx).

But after all, best is to deploy your app as atomic unit with client-less Oracle connectivity. Even if you use version redirection successfully, the functionality in one dll may differ from another and your results may not match your dev environment.

Comment: @TS: That's a really old article. These days the ODP.NET "xcopy" release has an option (machine_wide_configuration=false) to not use the GAC or modify the registry. It's better to use this means of installation than to simply blindly copy dlls.  See  ODAC121024Xcopy_32bit.zip located here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

Comment: @ChristianShay I agree. As a matter of fact there is nuget package `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` that does all you need client-less. So, this is end of story. How client-less installation works currently is a different question. I added package info to answer

Comment: Re-reading the original question, it seems as if he wants to use ANY version of the oracle client with his application, which is a non-starter because there are tight dependencies.